# Partially truncating log file contents based on size

Tags: windows, file, command-line, command-prompt, fsutil

I have log file `abcd.log` file of around 2GB of size, I need to keep latest contents of only `200MB` size and delete previous contents by using Windows in-built tool/ command line only.

What I found is to totally truncate the file by `copy, echo or touch` command but these are not for my requirement.

Comment: It's not very efficient to delete the start of a file's contents, as you have to copy the later content to the start of the file. And you must first scan for a proper line break so that you don't cut off the middle of a line. What logger are you using? Most loggers support file rolling with a specified maximum file size.

Comment: Its native_stderr.log file of websphere which doesn't have in-built logging support for it.